# Add wT*x+b after CNN Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

I have a problem.

I have to take the output of last conv layer of EfficientNet(shape=(,7,7,1280), I call this x) and then calculate H = wT*x+b.
My w is [49,49]. 
After that I have to apply softmax on H and then do [image] .

H and x have the same shape=[49,1280].

I can't find anything that help me to translate this in code python.
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you checked the official documentation of Keras and Tensorflow? You might use Conv2D and Dense.

Comment: I tried with this: 
    common_input = layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))    
    x=model0(common_input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 7*7,1280])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([49,49], seed=0), name='weight')
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([49], seed=0), name='bias')
    H = tf.matmul(W, x,transpose_a=True)
    H = tf.nn.softmax(H)
But I can't do the last step: Xi=Hi*Xi

Comment: So you want to multiply `H` and `X` elementwise, as they have the same shape? I see you use Tensorflow only without Keras.

Answer (score 1):

I see you use Tensorflow only (I mean without Keras).

If you want to multiply `H` and `X` elementwise, and `H` and `X` are tensors with the same shape, you may use the elementwise multiplication functionality available in Tensorflow. If they are not tensors, you may transform the variables in tensors. Check [here](https://riptutorial.com/tensorflow/example/10033/elementwise-multiplication) the official documentation with all the information.

Comment: If you want, look at my implementation. There is an error that I can't solve.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725611/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-inbound-nodes-error?noredirect=1#comment109182666_61725611