# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, conv-neural-network

I have to take the output of last conv layer of EfficientNet and then calculate H = wT*x+b. My w is [49,49]. After that I have to apply softmax on H and then do elementwise multiplication Xì = Hi*Xi.
This is my code:

```
common_input = layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))    
x=model0(common_input) #model0 terminate with last conv layer of EfficientNet (7,7,1280)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([49,49], seed=0), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([49], seed=0), name='bias')

x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 7*7,1280])
H = tf.matmul(W, x,transpose_a=True)
H = tf.nn.softmax(H)
#print(H.shape) (?,49,1280)
#print(x.shape) (?,49,1280)

x=tf.multiply(H, x)

p=layers.Dense(768, activation="relu")(x)
p=layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax", name="fc_out")(p)

model = Model(inputs=common_input, outputs=p)
```

But I got this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

```
<ipython-input-12-6ce3217f045c> in build_model()
     35     p=layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax", name="fc_out")(p)
     36 
---> 37     model = Model(inputs=common_input, outputs=p)
     38 
     39     return model

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Comment: Could it be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448652/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-inbound-nodes-while-trying)?

Comment: I don't think so. He's trying to merge three channels in one, I'm trying to modify the output matrix of conv layer and then put it in the fc layers.

Comment: which line is this error on?

Comment: How do you import `Model`?

Comment: I modified my post with the line. It is too long to put.
The last point of error is:

ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
   1392         """
-> 1393         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
   1394 
   1395         # Prevent cycles.

Comment: I import Model like this: model0 = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,pooling='avg',input_shape=(224,224,3)) and then I use model0.layers.pop() until the last layer is conv

Comment: I'm referring to the `Model` in this line `model = Model(inputs=common_input, outputs=p)`

Comment: from keras.models import Model

Comment: ok, so the problem is you can't put operations (like reshaping and multiplication) that are not layers between the neural network layers. Use a lambda layer for all the operations that are not layers

Comment: So the idea is correct but I have to use Lambda layers to do operations like reshape and multiplication, right?

Comment: I have put it down as an answer below, there might be typos or it might not exactly translate all the operations correctly (variables being replaced), just fix those. Hope the solution works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replaced the operations with a `Lambda` layer in the following code. Please excuse my shabby naming. Give this code a try.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([49,49], seed=0), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([49], seed=0), name='bias')

def all_operations(args):
    x = args[0]
    H = args[1]
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 7*7,1280])
    H = tf.matmul(W, x, transpose_a=True)
    H = tf.nn.softmax(H)
    x = tf.multiply(H, x)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 49*1280])
    return x

common_input = layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))    
x=model0(common_input) #model0 terminate with last conv layer of EfficientNet (7,7,1280)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Lambda(all_operations)([x, H])

p=layers.Dense(768, activation="relu")(x)
p=layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax", name="fc_out")(p)

model = Model(inputs=common_input, outputs=p)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give you a feedback asap

Comment: Ok, I modified only H because it isn't defined before Lambda layer.
Only one thing: Dense layer's output is (None, 49, 768)  and fc_out's output is (None, 49, 8).
How can I modify the code to have output like (None, 768) and (None, 8)?

Comment: @EliaFabbris before you feed the dense layer, you can do a reshape of x to `[-1, 49*1280]`. I have changed my answer to reflect this. Also if you find the solution acceptable, please press the gray check mark beside the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my savior!
You have been very kind!

Comment: I'm trying to fit my model but I got errors. 
Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 40960 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 62720. [[{{node lambda_3/Reshape}}]]
I put my code as an answer below

Comment: ok, now the model works. I changed the import of efficientNet. I no longer need to use layers.pop().
Thanks!